# Android common Java class best practices

Tags: android, coding-style

I am building a new project which uses some Java class from my other projects. I just found a bug in one of my file and I have to fix it everywhere.

Is there a way or best practices to solve this issue.

I have now these projects:

- Project A (game)
- Project B (game)
- Project C (tutorial app)

in each projects I have these common classes:

- Settings.java
- Progress.java

Now I copy these files to each projects. All these files are identical and other than the bug I just found, I do not have to change them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about making your own Android Library Project and linking to it from the projects where you are willing to use it.

Here, take a look. [Explanation of different kind of projects you can create.](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html)

Comment: and how do I do that with Android Studio 1?

Comment: There's a great Vogella tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html).

Comment: @Olaia That is using Eclipse

Comment: You can create any kind of Android app or library with either IDE.

You even have a wizard on Android Studio. :)